# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) - python script

Tags: python, cgi, google-app-engine, yaml

I am trying to deploy a python application and I am receiving the following error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.

My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: python
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
env: flex
service: newservice
handlers:
- url: /
  script: hello.py

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I believe the problem is related to the yaml file, since I have deployed a sample application previously with no problems (using entrypoint), then when I added a new python script and referred to it on the yaml file (using the handlers, since it is a message blockers) I started to get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the mistake is in the `app.yaml` file - you used the `handlers` section which exists only for the standard GAE environment. Check the [`app.yaml` flexible Python runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) reference for details on how the file should look like. You have also plenty of examples in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible).

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I am now using entrypoint. Thank you.

Comment: @LucasGuerreiro you can upvote the answer as well :-)

Comment: I would love to, but I don't have enough reputation :)